# What is the function of holder.itemView.setSelected in onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created inintClickListners function and that is called onCreateViewHolder.
Below is the code I created

```
initClickListeners(ViewHolder holder){

holder.itemView.setOnclickListener( v -> {
Data data = getItem(holder.getAdapterPostition());
data.setSelected(!holder.itemView.isSelected());
notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
});

holder.ivLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Data data = getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                        selectedAdpater.notifyFormDataChange(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                        String idx = data .getFormIdx();
                        notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                });
            });
}
```

Firstly, the itemView is the ConstrainLayout of ivLike.and ivLike is ImageView What I want is for the selectorDrawable to act differently when ivLike is pressed compared to when the itemView is pressed. While it applies separately when ivLike is pressed, it applies to the entire area when the itemView is pressed.
and I have defined holder.itemView.setSelected and holder.ivLike.setSelected in OnBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final Data data= (Data) getItem(position);

            holder.ivLike.setSelected(isLikeItem(data.getFormIdx()));
            holder.itemView.setSelected(data.isSelected());
        }
```

"To modify the code, I created holder.itemView.setSelected(!holder.itemView.isSelected()); within the initClickListeners function. While the selector worked as expected separately, what I really want is for itemView.setSelected to maintain its state based on a value within the Data. However, it doesn't retain its state, and I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Please help."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Data data = getItem(position);
    
        // Set the selection state for itemView
        holder.itemView.setSelected(data.isSelected());
    
        // Set the selection state for ivLike (if you want it to behave differently)
        holder.ivLike.setSelected(isLikeItem(data.getFormIdx()));
    }
```

And

```
void initClickListeners(ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Data data = getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        
        // Toggle the isSelected state of the Data object
        data.setSelected(!data.isSelected());

        // Update the itemView's selection state
        holder.itemView.setSelected(data.isSelected());

        // Notify the adapter that the item has changed
        notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    });

    holder.ivLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Data data = getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        
        // Modify the isSelected state of the Data object based on your logic
        // For example, toggle it or set it to a specific value
        data.setSelected(!data.isSelected());

        // Update the itemView's selection state
        holder.itemView.setSelected(data.isSelected());

        // Notify the adapter that the item has changed
        notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice but it didn't work
so, I'll use the payload, and if it works well, I'll leave a comment.